# How can I update the delivery date when using Woocommerce Subscription?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

How can I update the delivery date in Woocommerce Subscription?

In the documentation I did not find anything related. I thought I'd get the Metabox and upgrade via pure SQL, but there must be a better way.

Comment: I have seen that the site writes the delivery date in the table woocommerce_ordem_itemmeta, if it is some plugin I can modify the date?

Comment: See Print: https://screenshots.firefox.com/qVvKf1kdvgTwvlfp/cocolegal

In database:https://imgur.com/R3wvfoh

Comment: See Print: https://screenshots.firefox.com/qVvKf1kdvgTwvlfp/cocolegal

In database:https://imgur.com/R3wvfoh

MetaKey: https://pastebin.com/kD4agZUU

Comment: I'll send you the plugins my client is using. Is it any of these?

Image:https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/bace91e4-21c5-4001-b7aa-366e78deb8c6.png

Comment: It looks like it's the WooCommerce TM Extra Product Options plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
 $g = wc_get_order_item_meta($item_id,'_tmcartepo_data');
            $g[1]['value'] = 'Segunda';//Dia de Entrega
            $g[2]['value'] = '28/08/2018';//Data de Entrega
            wc_update_order_item_meta($item_id,'_tmcartepo_data',$g);
```